# How to influence execution's priority of the custom Request class?

Tags: laravel, request, middleware

As you might already know from the docs, Laravel's custom Request class (***make:request*** using artisan) provides a possibility to keep validation rules inside of it. So, I have the following code's examples to describe the problem of the prioritization better:

1. api route

```
    Route::post('/suggest', [SuggestionController::class, 'store'])
    ->middleware(['auth:sanctum']);
```

2. Request class

```
    class SuggestionRequest extends FormRequest
    {
        public function authorize()
        {
            return $this->user() && $this->user()->hasRole('sales manager');
        //  return true;
        }
    
        public function rules() {...}
    }
```

Here, I want to force my vendor middleware ***auth:sanctum*** (*which checks if the current user has a token*) to be executed before the SuggestionRequest class calls its own *authorize* method, because it doesn't make sense to validate the request's data and then check if the user is authenticated. Also, there's no need to have a quite similar logic in both places. Which way should I refactor my code? Are there any good approaches for it?

Comment: Try defining middleware `$middlewarePriority` in `App\Kernel`

`    $middlewarePriority = [
        \YourMiddlewareClassForSanctum::class
    ];`

Use this as a guide
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/19565

Comment: The request has to pass through all assigned middlewares before reaching the form request / controller action, so your expected result is the standard Laravel behavior.

Comment: @Remul yes, right, but it reaches the form request first in my case.. can beforeMiddleware resolve the problem?

Comment: As you can see [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php#L42) the default auth middleware is already a beforeMiddleware, did you change anything in `App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate`?

Comment: @Remul no, i didn't, and this class has only the redirectTo method

Comment: How are you verifying that it reaches your form request first? Just because you might get `null` with `$this->user()` in your form request does not mean that it did not pass through the `auth:sanctum` middleware. An easy way to verify would be to add a `dd('form request')` in the authorize method in your form request and a `dd('middleware')` before this [line](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php#L42) and then see what gets printed when you try to access the route.

Comment: I've just tried your way but nothing has changed. I was catching the errors using feature tests, dd() helper inside there and also catching the errors by this "AuthenticationException" class inside App\Exception\Handler.php. I see that any form request's class has the failedAuthorization method where you can throw its own errors, but in my way the previous steps were simillar and they didn't help. Thanks for trying to resolve it! I'll continue researching at the code

Comment: @Remul so, it's just printing me a "form request", i'm still surprised a bit, but maybe there is just a small mistake somewhere in my code

Comment: Did you add both dd() statements? one in the form request and one in the file in the vendor folder?

Comment: Yes, I did it: 
1) namespace Illuminate\Auth\Middleware; 
2) namespace App\Http\Requests;

Comment: @ANYADOLINKA Ok very strange, kinda out of ideas then, sorry for not being able to help you more.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... can you provide that method signature that your route is pointing to?

Comment: Thanks, sure I can.
`public function store(Authenticatable $user)`
but before that it uses the DI like that:
`private $service;
    public function __construct(SuggestionService $service)
    {
        $this->service = $service;
    }`
and this service takes in its constructor the form request then by resolving it from the container

Comment: well, i've just determined where is the problem hides just removing all the dependencies from my controller including this service's DI ^ ... So, the middleware prints message from its parent class first :o

Comment: i'm so grateful to you guys, thanks a million